# React. Streaming JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, streaming, server-side-rendering

I don't have any backend logic and database. For data I just use a json file of humans.
Here it is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Andrew"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Daniel"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Frank"
  }
]
```

Can I somehow stream this JSON file in React (i.e. on client side) to, for example, retrieve only the first two notes and return the array?  I tried FS module but it only works for SSR. Or there's no way I can runtime stream it getting desired data? I just don't wanna return the whole array since I'm trying to imitate a backend database

Comment: That won't be a valid JSON array, you should put the filtering logic on the serverside.

Comment: I see. So there's no way to filter a json file without serverside

Comment: If it is already loaded in client memory what's the point of "streaming" it? You prob just want to filter it

Comment: There's [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) by @dominictarr however I'm not sure if it'll work with the browser.